# Ruby on Rails parameter not being saved on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, strong-parameters

I have one form in views of controller `customer_tasks` that uses a dropdown menu with column names from model `customer`.
In the form, that dropdown menu is called with the following:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :search_column1 %><br>
  <%= select_tag :search_column1, options_for_select(Customer.translated_searchable_columns, params[:search_column1]), :include_blank => true %>
</div>
```

In my model `customer` the dropdown is generated with:

```
def self.searchable_columns
  wanted_columns = ['id', 'aa_code', 'name' ]
  self.column_names.select{ |column| wanted_columns.include?(column) }
end

def self.translated_searchable_columns
  columns = self.searchable_columns
  result = columns.map{ |column [Customer.human_attribute_name(column.to_sym), column] }
  result
end
```

In the `customer_tasks` controller I have the `:search_column1` included on permitted parameters like:

```
def customer_task_params
  params.require(:customer_task).permit(:task_name, :period, :client_type, :search_column1, search_column1: [])
end
```

But the output of the `development.log` is:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"H4waTsM4D1+EZX+deFozJut6FRS36sVQe7d7a1oRK2w=", "customer_task"=>{"task_name"=>"blah", "period"=>"", "client_type"=>"Γ"}, "search_column1"=>"aa_code", "commit"=>"Ενημέρωση Customer task", "locale"=>"el", "id"=>"4"}
```

The dropdown is working and sending the chosen option.
Why despite the fact that the parameter is permitted in the controller, it is not being saved/written to the database?

Why `"search_column1"=>"aa_code"` appears outside the parameters to the database?

What I am missing here?

Comment: Can you add the controller code where you actually attempt to make any changes to the database, eg do `update_attributes` or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) that's why `"search_column1"=>"aa_code"` appears outside the parameters to the database., if you use [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) it will go in the `customer_task` hash.

Change your `select_tag` to:

```
<%= f.select :search_column1, options_for_select(Customer.translated_searchable_columns, params[:search_column1]), :include_blank => true %>
```

Comment: If I try with `f.collection_select` I have the error:
wrong number of arguments (3 for 4..6)

What other alternatives I can use?

Comment: @PauloFidaldo you are right!

`<%= f.select :search_column1, options_for_select(Customer.translated_searchable_columns, params[:search_column1]), :include_blank => true %>`
Problem solved.
Many thanks!